# Chrome: transparent white on white background is not white

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've noticed an oddity in chrome concerning white overlay.
I have a white background (#ffffff) and on it there's a white overlay (also #ffffff) with opacity 0.8.

Here's the css:

```
.story {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   background: white;
   width: 300px;
   height: 320px;
   font-size: 12pt; 
}

.story-cover {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
   background: no-repeat center;
   background-size: cover;
}

.story-content {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 65%;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 10;
}

.story-content::before {
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

The result is this:
[image]

it's hard to notice so I've enhanced the levels inside the red square.
The right side is pure white #ffffff and the left side is #fefefe according to photoshop.

It's worth noticing that this is a chrome issue, firefox renders everything fine.

Is there a Chrome rendering expert who can clarify what is going on?

Edit: I've created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVrQpe) that helps to illustrate the problem.

Comment: That looks like a Chrome bug—you might want to report it on https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @ptelad I can't reproduce from your Codepen (for me both squares are 100% white). What's your exact Chrome version, and which platform are you on?

Comment: @thomasfuchs - Windows 7 Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m.
Did you try to take a screenshot and check the values in an editing software?
It's really hard to notice using the naked eye, I first noticed this when I viewed my monitor from the side.